# How to build and install flann and other libraries with python virtual environment(conda) using cmake on ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, anaconda, point-cloud-library, flann

I want to build and install(using Cmake) PCL on ubuntu18.04 but for this, I need to install Flann, eigen, vtk etc. but I want these to use conda virtual environment.

I was trying to build and install Flann using Cmake but I also want it to install pyflann(python bindings of flann) in virual environment(conda) but when after build by command

```
   cmake ..
   make
```

in build folder of source code.I used

```
   sudo make install
```

and tested the installation in python

```
  import pyflann
```

This all installed flann(pyflann) in core python of ubuntu but now I want to install it in virtual environment and also in a specifies directory.

While installing VTK I tried to change interpreter path in cmakCache.txt file and then run `make` and `sudo make install` for vtk but this also not worked

`import vtk` not worked.